# .htaccess RewriteRule to allow levels of sub-directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following RewriteRule code

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /page.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2&submenu2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /page.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php?menu=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

What I need it to do i this:

If the url is something like `mydomain.com/test` go to `mydomain.com/page.php?menu=test`

If the url is something like `mydomain.com/test/site` go to `mydomain.com/page.php?menu=test&submenu=site`

If the url is something like `mydomain.com/test/site/stuff` go to `mydomain.com/page.php?menu=test&submenu=site&submenu2=stuff`

These seem to clash with each other though.

Any idea how I can improve it to make it work.?

Comment: Use `[^/]+` instead of `.*`.

Comment: So `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$` ???

Comment: Hmm… still seems to clash unless I comment out the last of the three lines. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you test that rules are clashing?

Comment: Here's the error message that gets logged - `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2&submenu2=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?menu=$1 [L,QSA]
```